# Посчитать сумму ul>li

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день, ребят подскажи что не так, нужно посчитать сумму чисел в корзине.
Надо учитывать, то значение в `.price` может меняться.

Имею вот такой вод код:

```
 window.onload = function(){
   var sum = 0;
   $('.cart-list li').each(function(){
      sum+=parseInt($('.price', this).text());
   });
    $('#res').html(sum);;
  }
```

HTML следующий:

```
<li id="cart-'.$row['id'].'">
    <div class="image">
        <span>
            <img src="'.$row['img'].'" alt="'.$row['name'].'" width="87" height="87"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="text-holder"> <strong class="name">'.$row['name'].'</strong>
        <p>'.$row['desc'].'</p>
        <p> <i>'.$row['ingridient'].'</i>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="cart-hold">
        <div class="combobox">
            <a class="dec" onclick="minus(\''.$row['id'].'\');">&lt;</a>
            <a class="inc" onclick="plus(\''.$row['id'].'\');">&gt;</a>
            <input type="text" id="input-'.$row['id'].'" value="1" disabled></div>
        <div class="price-box">
            <span class="regular-price">
                <span class="price" id="price-'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['price'].'</span>
                <span style="display:none" id="prices-'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['price'].'</span>
                грн.
            </span>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="del nh_cart_delete" onclick="delItems(\''.$row['id'].'\');">X</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: сделайте функцию `updateSum` в которой будет код из вашего обработчика и вызывайте когда надо

Comment: например, в keyup/blur инпута

Comment: А в чем проблема-то? Что именно не работает?

Comment: Просто не могу понять почему он не выводит сумму <script>
  window.onload = function(){
  var sum = 0;
  $('#test').each(function(){
      sum+=parseInt($('.preice', this).text());
  });
  $('#res').html(sum);;
  }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<ul id="test">
 <li><div class="preice">50</div></li>
 <li><div class="preice">50</div></li>
 <li><div class="preice">50</div>0</li>
 <li>10</li>
 <li>12</li>
</ul>
<span id="res"></span> результат 505050

Comment: @OpaNa, а что выводит?

Comment: результат 505050 Он не суммирует какого-то черта, уже вроде и переоброзовал parseInt

Comment: сделайте минимальный воспроизводимый пример: тут в сниппете, либо например на jsfiddle

Comment: @Grundy, вот фидл с его версткой: https://jsfiddle.net/venzell/fx25dhmv/ и на нем проблема не воспроизводится

Comment: @OpaNa, проверьте содержимое переменных. С js-кодом у вас все ок.

Comment: Да, действительно все работает, взял пример @VenZell и воспользовался советом Grundy теперь все замечательно, пока не понял как давать репу, но спасибо за уделенное время

Comment: @OpaNa, я оформил в виде ответа. Если он вас устраивает, вы можете принять его, отметив его верным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте содержимое переменных. С javascript у вас все ок.

Вот ваш пример со слегка упрощенной версткой:

```js
var sum = 0;
$('.cart-list li').each(function() {
  sum += parseInt($('.price', this).text());
});
$('#res').html(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="cart-list">
  <li id="cart-1">
    <div class="cart-hold">
      <div class="price-box">
        <span class="regular-price">
                <span class="price" id="price-1">1000</span>
        <span style="display:none" id="prices-1">1000</span> грн.
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li id="cart-2">
    <div class="cart-hold">
      <div class="price-box">
        <span class="regular-price">
                <span class="price" id="price-2">1000</span>
        <span style="display:none" id="prices-2">1000</span> грн.
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

попробуйте

```
sum+=parseInt($('.price', this).text(),10);
```

или

```
sum+=parseInt($('.price', this).text().trim(),10);
```